# Problems with Java's FileWriter (OS X)

Tags: java, macos, filewriter

I'm using OS X (10.9 Mavericks) and I've got no idea why this code is giving me a blank output - meaning it gives no output at all, not even an exception.

Code snippet (created using ItelliJ IDEA):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String textFile = "hello.txt";
    try {
        FileWriter scribe = new FileWriter(textFile, true);
        scribe.write("Hello! Is it me you're looking for?");
        scribe.close();
    }
    catch (IOException iox) {
        System.out.println("ERROR with: " +textFile);
    }
}
```

Upon further inspection, it was simply an error with the 'cat' terminal command somehow failing to find the files on the system. Thanks to everyone who pitched in :)

Comment: What do you mean by "get a blank output"?

Comment: No exceptions? Only "blank output?

Comment: @NicolásCarlo `close()` will `flush()`.

Comment: Put this line inside your catch block: `iox.printStackTrace();`.Does that help?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thanks, I never remember that...

Comment: Just tried it on Mavericks with IntelliJ IDEA. Works perfectly. Need more explanation on what's going on or its too localized.

Comment: I just tried it as well, and it works fine. Is it possible "hello.txt`"is being held open by another program, or perhaps you don't have write permissions? Or perhaps you are looking at the wrong "hello.txt" (maybe left over from a previous run of the program in a different location)?

Comment: Fixed the bit about "no output" to make it clearer. I've tried changing the name to a couple of other things such as: "test_hello.txt" and "file_does_not_exist.txt" making sure there weren't any existing file mixups. I think I should add something: using terminal I ran 'cat hello.txt', as I expected nothing turns up. The file hasn't been written to the computer's drive at all.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you need to use a FileWriter?

With the addition of java.nio in 1.7, there are better ways of writing to a file.

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.nio.charset.Charset;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    public class Scribe {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
        {
            try (BufferedWriter scribe = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("hello.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset()))
            {
                scribe.write("Hello! Is it me you're looking for?");
            }
        }
    }
```

Try this one out and see if you still get blank output.

Comment: This doesn't really address the issue the OP is encountering in the first place.

Comment: I think the issue is not being able to write to a file. The above snippet will write to a file.

Comment: That's a very good question :-), here's another option he can try to see if it will work. If it doesn't then we can start thinking about other IO issues.

Comment: Is your IDE set up with the latest version of Java (1.7) and did you use its autoimport functionality?

Comment: I edited the code snippet to have the necessary imports.

Answer (score -3):

```
public class WriteToFileExample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        String content = "This is the content to write into file";

        File file = new File("/users/filename.txt");

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(content);
        bw.close();

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you could elaborate on why you believe this code answers the OP's question.